# Setup BrowserSync and Ripple Emulator

Tags: javascript, cordova, gulp, browser-sync, livereload

I'm currently developing hybird application with Cordova platform and debug it using Ripple Emulator.

The application itself doesn't really depends on native API of the target platform so I could test it with some simulation features that offered by Ripple emulator without worry. Every time i made change to the source files, my gulp task compile the javascript (I'm using ES6 with babel) and pack it with browserify automatically.

However, I need to reload the browser tab so I can see the change, not to mention that ripple will reload it's module and engine if i reload the tab.

Due this inefficiency, I tried to create a gulp task that would reload (inject the change to the) browser automatically. I use following setup:

```
gulp.task('cordova-prepare', function() {
    exec('cordova prepare');
});

gulp.task('reload', function() {
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('script', function() {
    var bundler = browserify("./src/Main.js");
    bundler.transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"]});

    bundler.bundle()
        .on('error', function(err) { gutil.log(err); })
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/scripts'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.js', ['script']);

    gulp.watch('./www/**/*.html', ['cordova-prepare', 'reload']);
    gulp.watch('./www/**/*.css', ['cordova-prepare', 'reload']);
    gulp.watch('./www/**/*.js', ['cordova-prepare']);
});

gulp.task('watch-source', ['script'], function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.js', ['script']);
});

gulp.task('ripple', ['script', 'watch'], function() {
    var options = {
        keepAlive: false,
        open: true,
        port: 4400
    };

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "http://localhost:" + options.port + "/?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0"
    });

    ripple.emulate.start(options);
});
```

The main problem is, whenever I made changes to the javascript files, it will reload the tab instead of injecting the changes. I also not quite sure what `cordova prepare` commands for, but it seems necessary to create the web app for current platform on `platform` folder.

Notice that I use `stream()` on `script` task in order to inject the javascript, but its not working

What I was expect is when I change some files, it will inject the new files into the browser tab (including html and css)

Any ideas?

Comment: ["Changes you make will either be injected into the page (**CSS & images**) or will cause all browsers to do a full-page refresh."](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-files)

Comment: But it doesn't mention when the injection occur and when the full reload occur, is there something I can do to force it inject the changes?

Comment: CSS & images -> injection, everything else -> reload